# Printing fails after first print with Centos 6 and HP LaserJet P3015dn printer

Tags: printing, cups, centos6

Centos 6 recognises and configures a HP LaserJet P3015dn printer connected via USB. This machine is being configured as a small group file/print server. I can print a test page, which is processed/printed correctly. The next time printing is attempted (say printing a second test page), the page is not printed and the printer is set to disabled. The status of the printer is stated as:

```
Stopped - /usr/lib/cups/backend/hp failed
```

in the printer configuration dialogue.

`/var/log/cups/error_log` contains this information (first two lines were there prior to the failed print job)

```
E [24/Jun/2004:09:12:57 +0100] Returning HTTP Forbidden for Resume-Printer (ipp://localhost/printers/HP-LaserJet-P3010-Series) from localhost
E [24/Jun/2004:09:20:59 +0100] Returning HTTP Forbidden for CUPS-Delete-Printer (ipp://localhost/printers/HP-LaserJet-P3010-Series) from localhost
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] The following messages were recorded from 09:36:43 AM to 09:37:28 AM
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] Adding start banner page "none".
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] Adding end banner page "none".
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] File of type application/vnd.cups-banner queued by "gavin".
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] hold_until=0
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] Queued on "HP-LaserJet-P3010-Series" by "gavin".
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] job-sheets=none,none
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] argv[0]="HP-LaserJet-P3010-Series"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] argv[1]="28"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] argv[2]="gavin"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] argv[3]="Test Page"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] argv[4]="1"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] argv[5]="job-uuid=urn:uuid:b3370a97-4ab6-3451-40a2-6239b13fa3e1 job-originating-host-name=localhost"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] argv[6]="/var/spool/cups/d00028-001"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] envp[0]="CUPS_CACHEDIR=/var/cache/cups"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] envp[1]="CUPS_DATADIR=/usr/share/cups"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] envp[2]="CUPS_DOCROOT=/usr/share/cups/www"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] envp[3]="CUPS_FONTPATH=/usr/share/cups/fonts"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] envp[4]="CUPS_REQUESTROOT=/var/spool/cups"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] envp[5]="CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/lib/cups"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] envp[6]="CUPS_SERVERROOT=/etc/cups"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] envp[7]="CUPS_STATEDIR=/var/run/cups"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] envp[8]="HOME=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] envp[9]="PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] envp[10]="SERVER_ADMIN=root@electra.geog.ucl.ac.uk"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] envp[11]="SOFTWARE=CUPS/1.4.2"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] envp[12]="TMPDIR=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] envp[13]="USER=root"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] envp[14]="CUPS_SERVER=/var/run/cups/cups.sock"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] envp[15]="CUPS_ENCRYPTION=IfRequested"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] envp[16]="IPP_PORT=631"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] envp[17]="CHARSET=utf-8"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] envp[18]="LANG=en_US.UTF-8"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] envp[19]="PPD=/etc/cups/ppd/HP-LaserJet-P3010-Series.ppd"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] envp[20]="RIP_MAX_CACHE=8m"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] envp[21]="CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-banner"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] envp[22]="DEVICE_URI=hp:/usb/HP_LaserJet_P3010_Series?serial=VNBV993GM4"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] envp[23]="PRINTER_INFO=Hewlett-Packard HP LaserJet P3010 Series"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] envp[24]="PRINTER_LOCATION=electra.geog.ucl.ac.uk"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] envp[25]="PRINTER=HP-LaserJet-P3010-Series"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] envp[26]="CUPS_FILETYPE=document"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] envp[27]="FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-postscript"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/bannertops (PID 2858)
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/pstops (PID 2859)
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] Started backend /usr/lib/cups/backend/hp (PID 2860)
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] load_banner(filename="/var/spool/cups/d00028-001")
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] Page = 612x792; 12,12 to 600,780
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] Page = 612x792; 12,12 to 600,780
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] slow_collate=0, slow_duplex=0, slow_order=0
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] Before copy_comments - %!PS-Adobe-3.0
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] %!PS-Adobe-3.0
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] %%BoundingBox: 12 12 600 780
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] %cupsRotation: 0
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] %%Creator: bannertops/CUPS v1.4.2
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] %%CreationDate: Thu 24 Jun 2004 09:36:43 AM BST
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] %%LanguageLevel: 2
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] %%DocumentData: Clean7Bit
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] %%Title: (Test Page)
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] %%For: (gavin)
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] %%Pages: 1
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] %%DocumentSuppliedResources: font Monospace
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] %%+ font Monospace-Bold
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] %%+ font Monospace-BoldOblique
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] %%+ font Monospace-Oblique
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] %%EndComments
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] Before copy_prolog - %%BeginProlog
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] STATE: +connecting-to-device
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] prnt/backend/hp.c 762: ERROR: cannot open channel PRINT
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] Backend returned status 1 (failed)
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] Printer stopped due to backend errors; please consult the error_log file for details.
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] End of messages
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] printer-state=5(stopped)
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] printer-state-message="/usr/lib/cups/backend/hp failed"
D [24/Jun/2004:09:37:28 +0100] [Job 28] printer-state-reasons=paused
```

`/var/log/messages` contains the following reports associated with the recognition of the printer and the failed print job:

```
Jun 24 09:35:07 electra kernel: usb 1-8: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 2
Jun 24 09:35:07 electra kernel: usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=03f0, idProduct=8d17
Jun 24 09:35:07 electra kernel: usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jun 24 09:35:07 electra kernel: usb 1-8: Product: HP LaserJet P3010 Series
Jun 24 09:35:07 electra kernel: usb 1-8: Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
Jun 24 09:35:07 electra kernel: usb 1-8: SerialNumber: VNBV993GM4
Jun 24 09:35:07 electra kernel: usb 1-8: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Jun 24 09:35:07 electra kernel: usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 2 if 0 alt 1 proto 2 vid 0x03F0 pid 0x8D17
Jun 24 09:35:07 electra kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver usblp
Jun 24 09:35:07 electra udev-configure-printer: invalid or missing IEEE 1284 Device ID
Jun 24 09:35:08 electra hp[1942]: io/hpmud/pp.c 627: unable to read device-id ret=-1
Jun 24 09:35:09 electra python: io/hpmud/pp.c 627: unable to read device-id ret=-1
Jun 24 09:35:51 electra kernel: usblp0: removed
Jun 24 09:37:28 electra hp[2860]: io/hpmud/dot4.c 254: unable to read Dot4ReverseReply data: Resource temporarily unavailable exp=2 act=0
Jun 24 09:37:28 electra hp[2860]: io/hpmud/dot4.c 330: invalid DOT4InitReply: cmd=0, result=20#012, revision=0
Jun 24 09:37:28 electra hp[2860]: prnt/backend/hp.c 762: ERROR: cannot open channel PRINT
```

I am now at a loss as to how to proceed to get this printer working on my Centos machine. How can I configure the machine to print more than a single print job without needing to be unplugged/plugged in repeatedly?

Answer (score 1):

The HP LaserJet P3015dn is a fully-supported printer under Linux and CUPS. The "dn" designation means "duplex and networking". As such, a quick clean way to rule out your workstation and (bleh) USB connectivity is to connect this printer via ethernet. That's probably the better approach to take long term anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered contacting HP for possible printer driver and/or firmware updates?

Comment: My first inclination was that this is a failure in the Linux stack side of things. This has been plugged into a SOHO NAS running Debian and working fine for sometime.

Comment: You may be able to confirm this with one of the bootable distros.